# How can I remove these windows for cleaning?

Tags: windows

I'm trying to figure out how to take these windows out of the frame for cleaning. I asked the landlord and he also doesn't know how that's done.

The windows consist of two panes that slide up and down in tracks. When closed the panes can be locked against each other in the middle.

I searched online but couldn't find anything, and I tried pretty much everything that didn't require excessive force to get them out.

Is this a standard window type with a well-known way to take them out?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Raise the inner sash about 6"  and then firmly pull the top of the it toward yourself.  The spring-loaded tracks on either side will give slightly and the top will pivot inward.  You can then tilt it to the right or left and free it.

Similar process with the outer sash although there is a section of the track down lower where the ridge that keeps the sash in is missing.  Lower it to that point and pull inward from the top.

If the window doesn't come easily, you can press the track on one side or the other with your palm to make it a bit easier.

To re-install, reverse the process.  Put the outer sash in first at the bottom, press in the top.  Slide it up.  Then put the bottom of the inner sash in, tilt it upward and press the top into place.

Comment: I'd suggest starting off by pushing against the tracks on either side, just to be sure they actually are spring loaded and designed to have the sashes removed. Non-removable sashes will look essentially the same and too much yanking on them could cause problems. If the tracks do give then this answer is 100% correct.

Comment: After raising the window a bit, I usually grab the top of the sash with both hands at each corner and with some pressure pulling in the top, I "twist" my wrists so the side of my palms press outward on the vinyl inserts which typically have a compressible foam behind them for insulation/ springiness/air barrier. BE REALLY CAREFUL reinstalling the widows!!! It is really easy to misalign the catch in the track to the tab on the window. I have seen the plastic get disfigured when it does not go back the way it should.

Comment: Thanks to all of you! Combining all these instructions indeed worked perfectly, and I can now clean my windows!